# Google form to load data from spreadsheet based on what is selected on first field

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form for doctors to update information about the patients progress based on latest consultation. Note that I want to "update" the information and not a new form to be filled.

So, based on the Patient name I choose from the list of patient name list, I want information to pre-fill the form with all the data already known about the patient.

I am aware of the solution to discuss on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcEju__MPtw . This needs doctor to have a link per patient. Instead I want to give only one Google forms link to doctor and based on which patient he choose the form gets filled with rest of the information from google sheets for that patient.

Is this possible? Please guide.

Comment: It is possible, there are some good [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) offered by google to get familiar with Apps Script and even links to JavaScript resources if you need. I would start at the beginning if you have never used Apps Script.